# Kill a Lambda function from another Lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a requirement that I need to kill Lambda function X from another function Y, when function state of X remains 'active' for 2 mins.

Using info from following documentation, I can get state of function X using get_function method, but then how to kill it from Y? I couldn't find anything helpful from docs here.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.update_function_event_invoke_config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't kill a lambda, but if you need it to stop at 2 minutes you can set the lambda timeout at 2 minutes. It will be stopped for you if it hits that time.

Comment: Yes that is the last resort, but is there no function in boto3 that could kill a Lambda specified? If not kill, can I terminate it using any other workaround?

Comment: You can't kill it from the outside, to the best of my knowledge. The timeout should be the first resort. That's what it's there for.